# Text is not even typing using typed.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, typedjs

I 'm trying to type the text using typed.js but its not working.

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>webpage</title>
<link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div id="particles-js"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src= "js/particles.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src = "js/app.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/typed.js" ></script>

<div class = "name">
Name
<div class = "about"><p>Developer <span class="typed">| Reader</span></p></div>
</div> 
<script type="text/javascript">
var typed = new Typed(".typed",{
                strings: ["Python Enthusiast","Stopped"],
                backSpeed: 40,
                typeSpeed: 40
              });
</script>
```

I want only reader text to be typed

Comment: `its not working` ... so what's happening instead

Comment: Does adding a cdn link instead help? @usmanharoon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I try your code with a cdn script tag it does type. There is probably an issue with your local `typed.js` file. See snippet below for reference:

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>webpage</title>
  <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="particles-js"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/particles.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typed.js/2.0.10/typed.min.js"></script>

  <div class="name">
    Name
    <div class="about">
      <p><span class="typed"></span></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var typed = new Typed(".typed", {
      strings: [
        "Developer | Reader",
        "Developer | Python Enthusiast",
        "Developer | Stopped"
      ],
      backSpeed: 40,
      typeSpeed: 40
    });
  </script>
```

**EDIT:** If you want all strings to be typed out you have to add them to your strings array. Also the part that should not change, in this case `Developer |` should be in every string so typed.js knows exactly how much to erase when backspacing. It will automatically keep the part that is common between all strings.

If you just want the part after `|` to be typed and the Reader part to be there already when you load (like you had in your own code) try the following:

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>webpage</title>
  <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="particles-js"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/particles.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typed.js/2.0.10/typed.min.js"></script>

  <div class="name">
    Name
    <div class="about">
      <p>Developer | <span class="typed">Reader</span></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var typed = new Typed(".typed", {
      strings: [
        "Reader",
        "Python Enthusiast",
        "Stopped"
      ],
      backSpeed: 40,
      typeSpeed: 40
    });
  </script>
```

In other words it looks like if you have some text already present in the element that you are calling typed on, you need to have this text also be present in your string array, otherwise it will skip some elements.

Comment: Now Its typing correctly.
But "Python enthisiast" this string is not printing:(

Comment: @usmanharoon I have updated my answer, is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Why there is two "Reader" string.Can you explain this?

Comment: typed.js seems to immediately replace what's inside of the span with class `typed`. By having the value Reader in the string array it knows that it should remove it with backspaces rather than immediately replace it.